# Autofilter only a specific range

Tags: excel

I have two tables in one worksheet.
One in columns `A:E` (Table 1) that needs to have an Autofilter (I have already implemented this) and another one from range `G1:I12` (Table 2).

I expect Table 1 to be filtered and Table 2  to remain unchanged.
The actual output is Table 1 filtered and Table 2 filtered by the same rows as Table 1.

Is it possible to have Table 2 unfiltered when Table 1 is filtered?

Comment: Show the input and the filtered output, because I can't follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. You need to split the tables into 2 different sheets then. Filters always filter/hide a whole row, partial row hiding is not supported in Excel.

Therefore side by side tables are not supported to filter individually, and need to be split into 2 sheets.

---

Alternatively you can have 2 tables one below the other (in the same sheet). In the following example both table contain the same data but the blue one is filtered by `A`.

[image]

Comment: i assumed it isn't possible.
I decided to split it in two different sheets, but this answer was the proof i needed, thanks for that.